# Mi bot de discord con JavaScript no responde

Tags: javascript

Mi bot de JavaScript no responde cuando hago un comando, aquí dejo el codigo.
Simplemente no responde

````
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando agregarle Intents y modificar "message" por "messageCreate". Con esto debería funcionar tu código.

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ],
});

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
    if (msg.content == "ping") {
        msg.reply("pong");
    }
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```